# mysql php query find longest matching parts of input

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get always the longest possible matches from my database.

**MyDatabase** ( id / phrase )
1: 'I'
2: 'go'
3: 'I go to school'
4: 'with'
5: 'with my dog named Gogo'
6: 'day'
7: 'every day'
8: 'except'
9: 'except weekends'
10:'weekends'

**User Input** = 'AwordThatsNOTinDB I go to school AwordThatsNOTinDB with my dog named Gogo every day except weekends AwordThatsNOTinDB'

So when the user inputs the above I'd like to get the following IDs in this order from the database as an array:
array(
"Not-Found", 
3, 
"Not-Found",
5, 7, 9,
 "Not-Found");

Comment: Why not `array(nf, 1, 2, nf, 4, nf, 7, 8, 10, nf)` ?

Comment: @vp_arth: Because I need to recreate the user input with the minimum amount of database matches!

Comment: it is not trivial task in common case

Comment: @vp_arth: Well, let's say there is a mp3 file connected to that match, then you want to have it read out fluently as long as possible and not cut up in every word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this solution:

1- select all strings from the database order by length of the string.

2- loop through my db strings and replace them in the user input. if the string changes I update the oringal string, and I add the id of the one I am in to the found array.

```
 $found_phrase=array();
 $string=strtolower('AwordThatsNOTinDB I go to school AwordThatsNOTinDB with my dog named Gogo every day except weekends AwordThatsNOTinDB');  

 // LIMIT DB-SEARCH  
 $string=preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string); // replace multiple spaces with one space
 $where=explode(" ",$string);
 foreach($where as $whereVal){
   $whereQuery=$whereQuery." phrase LIKE '%".$whereVal."%' OR";  
 }
 $whereQuery=rtrim($whereQuery,"OR"); // delete last OR
 $whereQuery="WHERE ".$whereQuery." ";    

 $query=$conn->prepare("SELECT id, phrase FROM table $whereQuery ORDER BY length(phrase) DESC");
 $query->execute();
 while($array=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $new_string=str_replace(strtolower($array['phrase']), "[{$array['id']}]", $string);
     if($new_string!=$string){
         $string=$new_string;
     }
 }
 $string=preg_replace('/([A-Z0-9,.]){1,} /i', ' Not-Found ', $string);
 $string=preg_replace('/\[([0-9])*\]/i', str_replace(array('[',']'), '',"$1"), $string);
 $string_array=explode(' ', $string);
 print_r($string_array);
```

Comment: Thanks CodeBird: So far I get an empty result, but I'll keep on testing. BTW would that be still a good method on a database with 100.000 phrases?

Comment: @TomSenner you might want to lower case both the input string and database phrase, as `str_replace` is case sensitive (check the edited code), unless you want your test to be case sensitive. As for the number for phrases, for sure the script will take longer when there are more phrases, or the input string is longer, but I don't see any other way that you can do that.

Comment: Works! Only the order is wrong and not like in the user input. Guess we're running into problems here because in the db_query we want the longest matches, but in the array it should be the order like it appears in the user input.

Comment: Thanks almost perfect now! Only the phrases that couldn't be found aren't mentioned with "Not-Found" at the right spot in the array. As we end up with IDs of the found ones it would even be better to have the PHRASE itself in the array if it could not be found. So the final array would be array( "AwordThatsNOTinDB", 3, "AwordThatsNOTinDB", 5, 7, 9, "AwordThatsNOTinDB");

Comment: @TomSenner check it out now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65608/discussion-between-tom-senner-and-codebird).

Answer (score 0):

Please get this as an array from database

```
$phrases=array(
    '1'=> 'I',
    '2'=> 'go',
    '3'=> 'I go to school',
    '4'=> 'with',
    '5'=> 'with my dog named Gogo',
    '6'=> 'day',
    '7'=> 'every day',
    '8'=> 'except',
    '9'=> 'except weekends',
    '10'=>'weekends'
);

$user_input = 'AwordThatsNOTinDB I go to school AwordThatsNOTinDB with my dog named Gogo every day except weekends AwordThatsNOTinDB';
$matches=array();

foreach($phrases as $id=>$phrase){
    $x=false;
    if(strpos($user_input,$phrase)!==false){


    if(!empty($matches)){
        foreach($matches as $key=>$match){
            if((strpos($phrase,$match)!==false) && $phrase !== $match)
                unset($matches[$key]);

            if((strpos($match,$phrase)!==false)){
                 $x = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    if(!$x)
        $matches[$id]=$phrase;


}
}
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Would this be a faster solution then the one below regarding a database with 100.000+ records? But I could fewer the db_query beforehand...explode the user input by " " and turn it into a LIKE statement before feeding the array!